# Upload files to database using ASP.NET MVC4 EF Code-First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**I need to upload files to database using ASP.NET MVC4  EF Code-First , any help please ?**

Comment: This is my model 
 
 public class File 
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Contract { get; set; }
    }


and i have this error :

EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Comment: Put everything relevant for the question in the actual question, not in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225446/Uploading-and-downloading-files-to-from-a-SQL-Serv

Use Google :)

I don't know if you're using razor or aspx, but you should be able to translate it if needed ;)

EDIT: Just realized, it doesn't matter :P

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you can not use HttpPostedFileBase in your entity model because there is no mapping for that in Database.

Create a ViewModel if you want to use HttpPostedFileBase.